# Word that sounds like dumpou or trumpou

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

I teach English online to children in China. One of my students has autism and cannot answer many questions. When I ask him what his name is, he always says "My name is Drumpou (or Trumpou)," which is not his name. He is trying to communicate something but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. It does sound like Trump. He is autistic, as I mentioned, but he could be making a political joke.

Answer (score 1):

Trump sounds like Trump. Many Chinese speakers whose English is not so hot will say 'ah' or 'oh' after English words, like: goodah, coldah.

This is the character for 啊 a, this is 哦 o. They are often added at the end of sentences for reasons of prosody.

You can say: 对 dui, meaning 'correct', but mostly you will hear 对阿 dui a 'correct'

Maybe he is making a (political) joke:
What's your name?
Trumpoh!

Comment: The official Chinese version of Donald Trump's last name is 特朗普 (te-lang-pu), so it has a "u" sound at the end. He might mean it as a joke, or he may just think of it as an English name that sounds good.

Comment: Although I believe this is the most correct answer. But I want to clarify that, adding "ah" or "oh" after English words is totally not the same situation with adding 啊 after 对. The reason for the former one is that Chinese speakers tend to have a vowel in every syllable, and only /n/, /ŋ/ can appear after the vowel. Therefore, a syllable like `/trʌmp/` is not valid in the eye of Chinese. They would tend to say `/'ʨuanpɤ/` so that it feels more natural for them. As for 对 vs 对啊, it's not a phonetic thing, but pragmatics.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is his [乳名](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B9%B3%E5%90%8D). Parents call their child using such 'nickname'. Kids aren't really aware that, whether to give their real-name or nickname to other to name him/her, sometimes.

It is just a guess. You may better consult his parent to reveal.